# Angular: Calling scope function in partial template included via ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have an anonymous controller within a directive. That controller, upon a particular event, opens a generic dialog and provides a partial template that is used to add some buttons to the generic dialog via ng-include.

Now within the generic dialog, once the user clicks on any of the provided buttons, I want a particular function in the anonymous controller be called. Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Controller:

```
angular.module('abc')
.directive('xyz', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.callThisFunc = function(){};
    }]
  }
}
```

Partial template:

```
<div>
<button label="CANCEL"
           ng-click="callThisFunc()">
</button>
</div>
```

Generic dialog template (different module than the abc module above):

```
<div ng-include="partial"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure of why you're using a directive there, but assuming you're actually using the directive somewhere in the view you won't get access to the callThisFunc method because the directive has `scope: {}`specified, which creates an isolated scope. I would either try setting `scope` to `false` or just create a controller with the controller declaration (not directive)

Comment: Thank you. I did try setting the scope to false that still does not call the function. I am reluctant to change this to a controller declaration because that will require a lot of changes in the code that I have, but if that is the only way to do it, then I guess I will have to go down that route

Comment: I'm not sure if it should work or not since I can't see the full html code. But I'm guessing the thing is you don't seem to be using the directive at all. If you can get your code on a fiddle I'll be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you again. The generic dialog is in the DOM at all points, except that I change the visibility of the dialog. I am trying to create a fiddle, but it is a large application and I am not certain how to create a simple fiddle example (I am a beginner on Angular and JS). I will update with the fiddle shortly

Comment: I meant the generic dialog and the xyzCtrl are both in the DOM at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "controllerAs" syntax

```
angular.module('abc')
.directive('xyz', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function() {
       var vm = this;

       vm.callThisFunc = function(){};

       return vm;
    }],
    controllerAs: 'xyzCtrl'
  }
}
```

partial template

```
<div>
<button label="CANCEL"
           ng-click="xyzCtrl.callThisFunc()">
</button>
</div>
```

generic dialog template

```
<div ng-include="partial" xyz></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think restrict should either be `EA` or `A` to use it as you suggested

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did try what you have suggested, and the function "callThisFunc" within the "xyzCtrl" is not being called. It seems like the scope for the partial template is the generic dialog.